# jQuery image slider caption on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, image-gallery, bxslider

I am using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions) to display multiple images. Now how to show image cation on image hover.

I have added `captions: true` but I want to show when user hover on image.

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" title="Sample 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" title="Sample 2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" title="Sample 3" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Sample 4" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" title="Sample 4" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Sample 5" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    pause: 4000,
    moveSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 4,
    slideWidth: 260,
    slideMargin: 13,
    touchEnabled: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false,
    captions: true,
    autoHover: true
});
```

My JSFiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/287/)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Simply add the CSS to do what you want. i.e. Set the caption to be hidden initially, and when a mouse hover is detected on any element, show the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set captions true option and set the visibility of the caption span class to none.

Than on mouseenter and mouseleave events show/hide the caption element.

Code:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    pause: 3000,
    moveSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 4,
    slideWidth: 260,
    slideMargin: 13,
    touchEnabled: true,
    pager: false,
    captions: true,
    controls: false,
    autoHover: true
});

$(".bxslider li").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find(".bx-caption").fadeIn();
})

$(".bxslider li").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find(".bx-caption").fadeOut();
});
```

Remember to add this to your css to initially hide the caption:

```
.bx-caption {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/HsDY9/

Comment: Why add jQuery `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` bindings to so many elements, this will unnecessarily increase the number of events being actively tracked. Even though this will work, this will not be the optimum solution.

Comment: The pure CSS solution is better, the only reason is for old IE support where :hover pseudo selector is buggy

Comment: IE6 and below exhibit buggy behavior with pseudo selectors. The plugins nowadays clearly mention that IE6 and below are not supported. Anyways, I shall add a clear msg on my answer. Thx for the update. :)

Comment: And for eventually CSS3 transition support http://caniuse.com/css-transitions, with jQuery is not a problem, I can't find more reasons :-)

Comment: Hello guys thank you so much for your help :) You both are right on your side.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of heavy jQuery manipulations or editing the original CSS file I suggest you add the following CSS to your code:

```
.bx-caption{
    display:none;
}

.bx-wrapper li:hover .bx-caption{
    display:block;
}
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/waBAM/)**

**Note:** In IE there must be declared a   for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the  element.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the bx-slider css and made some changes.
http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/288/

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
    /*additional styles*/
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.bxslider li:hover .bx-caption{
    bottom:0
}
```

As you can see the caption is set out of the slide and on hover is revealed with pure CSS